# Change visibility of attribute field/group of field in one layer based on checkbox or value map - QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, visibility

i'm using QGIS 2.18.3, in Win 7.

i want to know how to make attribute field or group of fields become visible or invisible based on value of other field

[image]

on picture above, i want to make my grup field "info" (red rectang) appear and disappear depend on value in my "status" field (blue rectang), either checkbox or value map.

Comment: Is this as a part of a QGIS plugin you are building or are you expecting to see the _change in status_ in the standard version of QGIS? It is not clear in your question.

Comment: @ZrSiO4. No, it's not a QGIS plugin. I just want to say that i have a shapefile layer, so when i add a new feature and then the feature attributes' pop-up appear, i want to make simple decision on visibility of "Main" container based on "Status" checkbox. When i check the "status" checkbox (blue rectang), the "Main" container (red rectang) will appear, and when i uncheck the checkbox, it will disappear. I keep learning the configuration in layer properties, but still meet a dead end.  I'm sorry that my language was not clear enough. thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Did you find any solution?
Possible solution, on **Drag and Drop Designer**, define a group container. Double click on the group container an define the **Control visibility by expression** to show only when your *Status field* is checked

[image]