# Conditional Visibility of a field based on checkbox or value map

Tags: qgis, qfield

Does anyone know how to show some fields only when a previous one has a not null value? I tried what was on [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283663/change-visibility-of-attribute-field-group-of-field-in-one-layer-based-on-checkb) but it didn't work since when I go to the expression dialogue it can't find the field

[image]

What I want to do is that the "Descripcion" group only shows up once `DESRI_RX` or `Rock_Type`, are not null (it needs to works on QField as well).

[image]

Comment: You should be able to see the field name in the expression builder, if not you could try to create your expression by hand typing the field name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also noted you cannot 'see' the field. But I have found a syntax that does work. Try...

```
attribute('DESRI_RX') is not null OR attribute('Rock_Type') is not null
```

I haven't tested, but hope that helps
O

Comment: Thanks, it worked well!!